# Does Sheltering Word remove an existing enchantment?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If a creature has an enchantment, like [Defang](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Defang), and I cast [Sheltering Word](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sheltering%20Word) on that creature, would the other enchantment be removed? Or does it need to be cast in response to the enchantment being played?

Comment: In one of the first tournaments I ever played in, I tried to cast... Mystic Veil I think it was, to remove a troublesome enchantment from an opponent's creature.  Lesson learned the hard way!  I wish I'd been a better player at that time, because it was one of the most absurdly powerful sealed deck pools I've received to this day.  A good player would have qualified for a Pro Tour or something without breaking a sweat, I'm sure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Auras do not target the creature they are attached to once they are in play.  Auras only target a creature while they are a spell on the stack. Yes casting **Sheltering Word** in response to **Defang** would make your creature untargetable, and therefore Defang would be countered on resolution.

> 114.1b Aura spells are always targeted. These are the only permanent spells with targets. An Aura’s target is specified by its enchant keyword ability (see rule 702.5, “Enchant”). The target(s) are chosen as the spell is cast; see rule 601.2c. An Aura permanent doesn’t target anything; only the spell is targeted. (An activated or triggered ability of an Aura permanent can also be targeted.)
>
> 702.11b “Hexproof” on a permanent means “This permanent can’t be the target of spells or abilities your opponents control.”

Comment: That means: One could cast Sheltering Word in response to Defang to counter Defang (since the aura *spell* targets). But once Defang is already attached, Sheltering Word does nothing to it (since the aura *permanent* doesn't target).

Comment: Correct. This is the same reason that you can bring back an Oblivion Ring from the graveyard to remove a Geist of Saint Traft. Only casting the spell targets, but entering the battlefield and attaching it does not. Note, however, if you cast Faith's Shield to give a creature protection from White, then the Aura _would_ fall off.